# Return false within anchor tag gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following statement

```
<a href="javascript: return false;" id="addNew1">ADD NEW ROW</a>
```

If I click on this I get the following error in my browser.

```
return not in function
```

I use the following JQuery function

```
$('#addNew,#addNew1').click(function(){
```

Do I need to include this in the function, the reason I do not add 'n # sign in is because the the page jumps to the top of the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="addNew1">ADD NEW ROW</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

1. The href attribute should point to a real URL that will serve the same purpose as the JavaScript if the JavaScript should fail for any reason. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).
2. The click handler should return false so the link isn't followed if the JavaScript doesn't fail (at which point the value of href doesn't matter).

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
<a href="#" id="addNew1">ADD NEW ROW</a>
```

---

```
$('#addNew, #addNew1').click(function() {
    // do stuff
    return false;
}
```

Another option would be this:

```
$('#addNew, #addNew1').click(function(e) {
    // do stuff
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Usually, if you want to prevent the default action, which in this case is the activation of the anchor, you do it inside the click handler.

Comment: True.  In a simple case, returning `false` in the `onclick` handler on the anchor (`<a>`) itself probably makes more sense than using jQuery--it's just easier to see what's going on.